# How making individual setting of commands for each Discord server(guild)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Like if admin of server writes "!setprefix $" then bot set prefix from "!" to "$" and it is only for server that admin on

Answer (score 0):

As I imagine it is in your bot, you set up at the beginning of the program:

```
const prefix = '!';
```

but you want to make sure that if the server admin writes the command `!setprefix $`, it will change it.
So, it's quite simple, you just have to check first if the author of the command
`!setprefix $` is the admin, simply with the following :

```
if (message.member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Admin'))
```

and consequently take the `$` parameter and set it in the prefix variable:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; 

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'setprefix') {
        prefix = args;
    }
```

Comment: What will happen if the bot restarts? Surely you don't want to have to set the prefix every time.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your trying this for multiple servers, and if you use the below answer it will be a global one just changeable by an admin, for this use case you could use a database if its a public bot I would suggest a database like Mongodb with mongoose or keyv. for starters, I would suggest using keyv as its easier

if not I would still suggest mongodb, but if it seems like overkill for a private sort of bot use a simple one like enmap.

guide for custom prefix with keyv: https://discordjs.guide/keyv/#installation

guide for custom prefix with enmap: https://enmap.evie.dev/complete-examples/per-server-settings